# There is a lot of space between each data when nested collection view is implemented in .NET MAUI in iOS

Tags: ios, mobile, maui

[Android image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46PD5.png) [iOS image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKnmo.png) Please refer the image how it shows a lot of spaces after each collectionview data. I have implemented a nested collection view for displaying data dynamically in .NET MAUI but I get lot of extra space after each collection view data in iOS. But it is working fine in android. Please refer below code

```
'''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:sample.sample.ViewModel"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:sample.sample.Model"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Yeap.sample"
             xmlns:searchbar="clr-namespace:sample.sample"
             x:Class="sample.sample.View.Attendancesample"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:PickupViewModel"
             xmlns:locals="clr-namespace:sample.sample.View"
             xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:sample.sample.Helpers"
             xmlns:mct="clr-namespace:CommunityToolkit.Maui.Behaviors;assembly=CommunityToolkit.Maui"
             Title="{local:Translate Pickup_Title}" BackgroundColor="#f7f4f4">
    <ContentPage.Behaviors>
        <mct:StatusBarBehavior StatusBarColor="#00000000"/>
        <mct:StatusBarBehavior StatusBarStyle="DarkContent" />
    </ContentPage.Behaviors>
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <conv:ImageHelper  x:Key="ImageHelper"/>
        
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <StackLayout>
        <ScrollView VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
            <StackLayout>
                <VerticalStackLayout>
                    <VerticalStackLayout BackgroundColor="White">
                        <HorizontalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center"  Margin="0,0">
                            <Label x:Name="CarplateNo" Text="" FontFamily="InterMedium" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="16" TextColor="#6C6C6C"/>
                            <Label  Text=" - " FontFamily="InterMedium" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="16" TextColor="#6C6C6C"/>
                            <Label x:Name="VechileId" Text="" FontFamily="InterMedium" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="16" TextColor="#6C6C6C"/>
                        </HorizontalStackLayout>
                        <!--Total-->
                        <HorizontalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                            <Label TextColor="black" Text="" FontFamily="InterMedium" FontSize="16"/>
                            <Label Text="" TextColor="#FFB82B" FontFamily="InterMedium" FontSize="16"/>
                            <Label TextColor="black" Text=" - " FontFamily="InterMedium" FontSize="16"/>
                            <Label TextColor="black" Text="" FontFamily="InterMedium" FontSize="16"/>
                            <Label Text="" TextColor="#FFB82B" FontFamily="InterMedium" FontSize="16"/>
                        </HorizontalStackLayout>
                        <!--Generate Buttons-->
                        <HorizontalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="4" >

                            <Button TextColor="white" ImageSource="qr_code.svg"  Text="{local:Translate Common_QRCode}" HeightRequest="50" ContentLayout="left,0"
                            BackgroundColor="#FFB82B" Margin="6" Clicked="Button_Clicked_1" />
                            <Button TextColor="white" ImageSource="directions_walk.svg"  Text="" HeightRequest="50" ContentLayout="left,0"
                            BackgroundColor="#FFB82B" Margin="6" Command=""  />
                        </HorizontalStackLayout>
                    </VerticalStackLayout>

                    <VerticalStackLayout BackgroundColor="#f4f4f4">
                        <Frame CornerRadius="20"  BackgroundColor="White" BorderColor="LightGray"  Margin="10,8"
                        Padding="{OnPlatform Android='1,0',iOS='10,10'} " HeightRequest="40">
                            <HorizontalStackLayout>
                                <Label Text="{x:Static model:Icons.Search}" FontSize="25" FontFamily="Icons" TextColor="Gray" Margin="15,6,0,0" />
                                <searchbar:BorderlessSearchbar x:Name="searchBar" Placeholder="{local:Translate  Pickup_Search_Title}" 
                               Margin="-20,0" TextColor="Black" PlaceholderColor="LightGray" TextChanged="SearchBar_TextChanged" />
                            </HorizontalStackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                        <!--BusStops and Passenger List-->
                        <VerticalStackLayout x:Name="collectionview">
                            <CollectionView EmptyView="No Results found" ItemsSource="{Binding Stop}" x:Name="busStopCollectionView">
                                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:BusStop">
                                        <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="0,0">
                                              <VerticalStackLayout>
                                            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#2B61B2" HeightRequest="45">
                                               
                                                <HorizontalStackLayout   Margin="5,0" Padding="0,6,0,0" VerticalOptions="Center">

                                                    <!--BusStops-->
                                                   <Label FontSize="15" FontAttributes="Bold"  
                                                    Text="" WidthRequest="320" VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White"/>

                                                    <Label FontSize="17" FontAttributes="Bold" 
                                                    Text="" TextColor="White" 
                                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                                                </HorizontalStackLayout>
                                            </StackLayout>

                                            <!--Passengers-->
                                            <CollectionView EmptyView="No Results found" x:Name="" ItemsSource="" >
                                                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="">
                                                            <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="0,0">
                                                        <Frame BackgroundColor="white" x:Name="Parent" BorderColor="White" CornerRadius="0" Margin="0,3"
                                               HasShadow="True" HeightRequest="78" Padding="10" >
                                                            <Frame.Triggers>
                                                                <MultiTrigger TargetType="Frame">
                                                                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                                                        <BindingCondition Binding="" Value="ECA" />
                                                                        <BindingCondition Binding="" Value="True" />
                                                                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                                                    <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="True" />
                                                                    <!--<Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Gray" />-->
                                                                </MultiTrigger>
                                                                <MultiTrigger TargetType="Frame">
                                                                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                                                        <BindingCondition Binding="" Value="ECA" />
                                                                        <BindingCondition Binding="" Value="True" />
                                                                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                                                    <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="True" />
                                                                    <!--<Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Gray" />-->
                                                                </MultiTrigger>
                                                                <MultiTrigger TargetType="Frame">
                                                                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                                                        <BindingCondition Binding="" Value="ECA" />
                                                                        <BindingCondition Binding="" Value="False" />
                                                                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                                                    <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False" />
                                                                    <!--<Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Red" />-->
                                                                </MultiTrigger>

                                                            </Frame.Triggers>

                                                            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command=""
                                                     NumberOfTapsRequired="1" CommandParameter="" />
                                                            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                                            <!--Image-->
                                                            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="Auto,*,Auto" Margin="-5" >
                                                                <Border Grid.Column="0" WidthRequest="70" HeightRequest="70" Stroke="White" StrokeShape="Ellipse" Margin="0,10" >
                                                                    <Image Aspect="AspectFill" Source=""/>
                                                                </Border>
                                                                <!--Name and Id-->
                                                                <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Start">
                                                                    <Label x:Name="PassengerName" TextColor="black" HeightRequest="30" Text="" FontSize="15"/>
                                                                    <Label x:Name="PassengerId" Text="" TextColor="Grey" />
                            
                                                                </VerticalStackLayout>
                                                                <!--Status-->
                                                                <Frame x:Name="radioBtn" Grid.Column="2" CornerRadius="{OnPlatform Android='30', iOS='22' }"  BackgroundColor="White" 
                                                               WidthRequest="45" HeightRequest="45" Margin="10,0" BorderColor="LightGrey">
                                                                    <Frame.Triggers>
                                                                        <DataTrigger TargetType="Frame" Binding="{Binding IsPickupCompleted}" Value="True">
                                                                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#80C551" />
                                                                            <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="#80C551" />
                                                                        </DataTrigger>
                                                                        <DataTrigger TargetType="Frame" Binding="{Binding IsPickupCompleted}" Value="False">
                                                                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White" />
                                                                            <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="LightGray" />
                                                                        </DataTrigger>
                                                                    </Frame.Triggers>
                                                                    <Label Text="" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                                                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" 
                                                                   TextColor="White" Padding="0,-1,0,0" >
                                                                        <Label.Triggers>
                                                                            <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="" Value="True">
                                                                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30" />
                                                                                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Icons" />
                                                                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{x:Static model:Icons.Bus}" />
                                                                            </DataTrigger>
                                                                            <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="" Value="False">
                                                                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="" />
                                                                            </DataTrigger>
                                                                        </Label.Triggers>
                                                                    </Label>
                                                                    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="" 
                                                                                      CommandParameter="{x:Reference radioBtn}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                                                                        <!--<TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />-->
                                                                    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                                                </Frame>

                                                            </Grid>

                                                        </Frame>
                                                                </Grid>
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                            </CollectionView>
                                        </VerticalStackLayout>
                                   

                                        </Grid>
                                       </DataTemplate>
                                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            </CollectionView>
                        </VerticalStackLayout>
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                </VerticalStackLayout>
                <VerticalStackLayout Margin="20,10,20,20" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                    <Button ImageSource="directions_walk.svg" Text="{local:Translate Common_DropOff}" BackgroundColor="#FFB82B" TextColor="White" ContentLayout="left,0"  Command=""/>
                </VerticalStackLayout>
                <!--Dropoff Button-->

            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        <HorizontalStackLayout  BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="End">
            <locals:BottomNavigation />
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
  
</ContentPage>'''
```

I tried all other layout but it has no effect on iOS devices. Can you suggest any alternate to fix this issue ?

Comment: A screenshot of the problem would greatly help.

Comment: Updated the image pls refer it.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot that app runs well on android?

Comment: updated with both images

Comment: Explain to me this line: <StackLayout <ScrollView VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand". What is "Start and expand" , what is the height of stack layout. How is the height of scroll view calculated, etc.

Comment: in .NET MAUI startandexpand property is used to control the layout and sizing of views within a layout container. It is often used in XAML to specify how a particular view should be positioned and sized within its parent layout.